# minitest mode in emacs running from home directory instead of project directory

Tags: ruby, emacs, minitest

When I try and run a test by pressing `C-c ,s` the test is not being run from the project directory but from my home directory, e.g.

```
 bundle exec ruby -Ilib\:test\:spec /Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/test/integration/contacts/import_contact_test.rb -ntest_primary_values_set_if_provided
```

The project directory is /Users/paulcowan/projects/crm.  Is there a way that I can specify the project directory?  If I am in the home directory then it does not pick up the correct rbenv version.

Comment: If you do `M-x cd RET /Users/paulcowan/projects/crm RET` does it work?

Comment: no, still runs from the home directory

Comment: What does `M-: (minitest-project-root) RET` give?